# How to return the success or failure result in the goroutine to the main function and fmt.Println the number of successes

Tags: go

I want to write the contents of the process function with a function different from the main function.

I want to count the number of urls that did not result in an error with "resp, err: = client.Do (req)".

I want to write the number of successes before fmt.Println ("Finish!") In the main function.

What should I do?

```
func main() {
    site_list := [][]string{
        {"site1","https://www.aaaa"},
        {"site2","https://www.bbbb"},
        {"site3","https://www.cccc"},
        {"site4","https://www.dddd"},
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    maxChan := make(chan bool, 2)

    for _, v := range site_list {
        maxChan <- true
        wg.Add(1)
        go process(v[1], maxChan, &wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Finish!")
}

func process(site_url string, maxChan chan bool, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    defer func(maxChan chan bool) {
        <-maxChan
    }(maxChan)
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", site_url, nil)
    client := new(http.Client)
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("client.Doエラー" + site_url)
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
}
```

Comment: Would you not use 2 channels to synchronise your code? The input channel to your goroutine can then produce the sites you want to process, and the output channel can receive the result?

Comment: create a work item struct (with URL and `error`) - pass pointer of work item to `process()` - and have it update the runtime error for any items. Tally at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment above, create a custom work item struct:

```
type urlItem struct {
    Name string
    Url  string
    Err  error
}
```

Use pointers, so that the `process()` function can update the underlying struct:

```
site_list := []*urlItem{
    &urlItem{"site1", "https://www.aaaa", nil},
    &urlItem{"site2", "https://www.bbbb", nil},
    &urlItem{"site3", "https://www.cccc", nil},
    &urlItem{"site4", "https://www.dddd", nil},
}
```

`process()` can then safely update it's particular work item (without the need for any mutexs or synchronization) as each go-routine gets a unique work item.

```
func process(site *urlItem, maxChan chan bool, wg *sync.WaitGroup) { /* ... */ }
```

Then tally the go-routine `errors` at the end:

```
var failCount int

for _, v := range site_list {
    if v.Err != nil {
        failCount++
    }
}
```

[Playground Example](https://play.golang.org/p/wOUZqygXqwy)

Comment: I was able to do what I wanted to do! I am very grateful for the details of the code!

Comment: There are two bad ratings on this question. Do you know why?

Comment: Don't take down-votes personally, but if I had to guess, usually folks like to see what work you had tried, to solve a problem - rather than simply asking *how* to implement a solution.

Comment: Thank you for your polite answer.

I was experimenting with how to append to slices and channels.

I did not mention that it would be redundant, but it may have been thought to be left all the work.

I will be careful in the future.
Thank you very much.